# How to cancel doctrine schema updates on Symfony?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

In production website, I tried to update Symfony and modules by doing `php composer.phar update`. The problem is that the updates have broken the website. So I decided to revert code and installed the source code from development server. I never updated the database with `bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

Now I am blocked because I can't update schema database in production server. When I do `bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`, there are a lot of doctrine table updates, such these:

```
ALTER TABLE livre ADD path VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE sylius_order_item_unit ADD CONSTRAINT FK_82BF226EE415FB15 FOREIGN KEY (order_item_id) REFERENCES sylius_order_item (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE sylius_order_item_unit ADD CONSTRAINT FK_82BF226E7BE036FC FOREIGN KEY (shipment_id) REFERENCES sylius_shipment (id) ON DELETE SET NULL;
ALTER TABLE sylius_payment_method ADD CONSTRAINT FK_A75B0B0DF23D6140 FOREIGN KEY (gateway_config_id) REFERENCES sylius_gateway_config (id) ON DELETE SET NULL;
ALTER TABLE sylius_payment_method_channels ADD CONSTRAINT FK_543AC0CC5AA1164F FOREIGN KEY (payment_method_id) REFERENCES sylius_payment_method (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE sylius_payment_method_channels ADD CONSTRAINT FK_543AC0CC72F5A1AA FOREIGN KEY (channel_id) REFERENCES sylius_channel (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE sylius_product ADD CONSTRAINT FK_677B9B74731E505 FOREIGN KEY (main_taxon_id) REFERENCES sylius_taxon (id);
ALTER TABLE sylius_product_channels ADD CONSTRAINT FK_F9EF269B4584665A FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES sylius_product (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE sylius_product_channels ADD CONSTRAINT FK_F9EF269B72F5A1AA FOREIGN KEY (channel_id) REFERENCES sylius_channel (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE sylius_product_options ADD CONSTRAINT FK_2B5FF0094584665A FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES sylius_product (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE sylius_product_options ADD CONSTRAINT FK_2B5FF009A7C41D6F FOREIGN KEY (option_id) REFERENCES sylius_product_option (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE sylius_product_image ADD CONSTRAINT FK_88C64B2D7E3C61F9 FOREIGN KEY (owner_id) REFERENCES sylius_product (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE sylius_product_image_product_variants ADD CONSTRAINT FK_8FFDAE8D3DA5256D FOREIGN KEY (image_id) REFERENCES sylius_product_image (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE sylius_product_image_product_variants ADD CONSTRAINT FK_8FFDAE8D3B69A9AF FOREIGN KEY (variant_id) REFERENCES sylius_product_variant (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE sylius_product_review ADD CONSTRAINT FK_C7056A994584665A FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES sylius_product (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE sylius_product_review ADD CONSTRAINT FK_C7056A99F675F31B FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES sylius_customer (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE sylius_product_taxon ADD CONSTRAINT FK_169C6CD94584665A FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES sylius_product (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE sylius_product_taxon ADD CONSTRAINT FK_169C6CD9DE13F470 FOREIGN KEY (taxon_id) REFERENCES sylius_taxon (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE sylius_product_translation ADD CONSTRAINT FK_105A9082C2AC5D3 FOREIGN KEY (translatable_id) REFERENCES sylius_product (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE sylius_product_variant ADD CONSTRAINT FK_A29B5234584665A FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES sylius_product (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE sylius_product_variant ADD CONSTRAINT FK_A29B5239DF894ED FOREIGN KEY (tax_category_id) REFERENCES sylius_tax_category (id) ON DELETE SET NULL;
ALTER TABLE sylius_product_variant ADD CONSTRAINT FK_A29B5239E2D1A41 FOREIGN KEY (shipping_category_id) REFERENCES sylius_shipping_category (id) ON DELETE SET NULL;
ALTER TABLE sylius_product_variant_option_value ADD CONSTRAINT FK_76CDAFA13B69A9AF FOREIGN KEY (variant_id) REFERENCES sylius_product_variant (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE sylius_product_variant_option_value ADD CONSTRAINT FK_76CDAFA1D957CA06 FOREIGN KEY (option_value_id) REFERENCES sylius_product_option_value (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE sylius_promotion_channels ADD CONSTRAINT FK_1A044F64139DF194 FOREIGN KEY (promotion_id) REFERENCES sylius_promotion (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE sylius_promotion_channels ADD CONSTRAINT FK_1A044F6472F5A1AA FOREIGN KEY (channel_id) REFERENCES sylius_channel (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE sylius_promotion_coupon ADD CONSTRAINT FK_B04EBA85139DF194 FOREIGN KEY (promotion_id) REFERENCES sylius_promotion (id);
ALTER TABLE sylius_shipment ADD CONSTRAINT FK_FD707B3319883967 FOREIGN KEY (method_id) REFERENCES sylius_shipping_method (id);
ALTER TABLE sylius_shipment ADD CONSTRAINT FK_FD707B338D9F6D38 FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES sylius_order (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE sylius_shipping_method ADD CONSTRAINT FK_5FB0EE1112469DE2 FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES sylius_shipping_category (id);
ALTER TABLE sylius_shipping_method ADD CONSTRAINT FK_5FB0EE119F2C3FAB FOREIGN KEY (zone_id) REFERENCES sylius_zone (id);
ALTER TABLE sylius_shipping_method ADD CONSTRAINT FK_5FB0EE119DF894ED FOREIGN KEY (tax_category_id) REFERENCES sylius_tax_category (id) ON DELETE SET NULL;
ALTER TABLE sylius_shipping_method_channels ADD CONSTRAINT FK_2D9833355F7D6850 FOREIGN KEY (shipping_method_id) REFERENCES sylius_shipping_method (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE sylius_shipping_method_channels ADD CONSTRAINT FK_2D98333572F5A1AA FOREIGN KEY (channel_id) REFERENCES sylius_channel (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE sylius_shop_user ADD CONSTRAINT FK_7C2B74809395C3F3 FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES sylius_customer (id);
ALTER TABLE sylius_tax_rate ADD CONSTRAINT FK_3CD86B2E12469DE2 FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES sylius_tax_category (id);
ALTER TABLE sylius_tax_rate ADD CONSTRAINT FK_3CD86B2E9F2C3FAB FOREIGN KEY (zone_id) REFERENCES sylius_zone (id);
ALTER TABLE sylius_taxon ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CFD811CAA977936C FOREIGN KEY (tree_root) REFERENCES sylius_taxon (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE sylius_taxon ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CFD811CA727ACA70 FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES sylius_taxon (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE sylius_taxon_image ADD CONSTRAINT FK_DBE52B287E3C61F9 FOREIGN KEY (owner_id) REFERENCES sylius_taxon (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

It seems that in production server, doctrine wants to update database regarding the updates I have done when I runned `php composer.phar update`

When I do the same thing in development server, I have only one update in list:

```
ALTER TABLE livre ADD path VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL;
```

This is the only update I need to do and I am supposed to do actually (the source code was reverted from development server, so there is no reason apparently why doctrine want still apply these updates).

Can I cancel unnecessary schema updates?

Comment: Could you try to clear cache and try to generate sql dump again? Probably metadata were cached.

Answer (score 0):

To fully revert production server from changes, made by composer, run:

```
php composer.phar install
```

This will **revert vendors on production** to the snapshot from **composer.lock** file. And if these DB changes were caused by wrong composer execution - they should dissapear.

Also, people usually run ***php composer.phar update*** only locally, then commit **composer.lock** file, and on servers execute only ***php composer.phar install*** command. It's safe and helps to avoid issues during deploy.

Another good practice is to use **[Doctrine Migrations](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html)**. You can test schema updates locally, and on servers  - just execute the same SQL, without running "doctrine:schema:update"